# How to check internet without Networkinfo(Java)

Tags: android, android-studio, callback, android-networking, internet-connection

Since `NetworkInfo` is deprecated I don't able to find any alternative solution.
I've tried `ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallbacks` but in this `OnNetworkUnavailable` is not working.

How to check for internet when a button is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Then use below method

```
public boolean isOnline() {

    boolean isConnected = false;
    ConnectivityManager connectivityMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        // Checking internet connectivity
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = null;
        if (connectivityMgr != null) {
            activeNetwork = connectivityMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo(); // Deprecated in API 29
        }
        isConnected = activeNetwork != null;

    } else {
        Network[] allNetworks = connectivityMgr.getAllNetworks(); // added in API 21 (Lollipop)

        for (Network network : allNetworks) {
            NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities = connectivityMgr.getNetworkCapabilities(network);
            if (networkCapabilities != null) {
                if (networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                        || networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
                        || networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET))
                    isConnected = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return isConnected;

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but read my question again as NetworkInfo is deprecated.

Comment: Hi @AmitGhosh yeah deprecated when it comes to use it beyond the due API of its deprecation, if you use it before the deprecation date it's Ok, that is why I commented `// Deprecated in API 29`, So you can use it until API 29, and starting from API 29 (or even the provided replacement in else branch can be used starting from API 21 .. Android Studio is smart enough of deprecation, if you use this method, no deprecation warning will raise up.

Comment: Your answer was the most helpful for me, thankyou for clearing this.

Comment: also if my minSdkVersion is 21 can I use this else{} part only?

Comment: @AmitGhosh You're right ... one more point I just want it to be more clear to you .. If you want your app to run on old mobiles you have to use deprecated code, because the SDK on these mobiles has no idea about the new SDK (non-deprecated methods), so there is no problem to use deprecated code as long as you use them in their intended API levels

Comment: <<a newbie doubt>> what if network info is removed by android studio in future and it got red in my code? does it happen?

Comment: Nice question.. it can't be removed from android studio as you've its SDK API level installed on Android Studio, I just want you to  CTRL + click on `NetworkInfo` class on android studio and see that class .. you'll see all the deprecated code still there but marked with `@Deprecated`, so they never remove code, but they upgrade it , and warn you if you use old code in newer API levels (by saying this particular method is now deprecated, it can run, but you should use newer methods in this particular API)

Comment: I just leveled up in my journey of android. Thanks for answering, you are great!

Answer (score 1):

```
private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
       ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
       return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
   }
```

Comment: getActiveNetworkInfo() is deprecated too, do you have an alternative to this.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun hasActiveInternetConnection(): Boolean {
try {
    val urlc: HttpURLConnection =
        URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
    urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test")
    urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close")
    urlc.connectTimeout = 1500
    urlc.connect()
    return urlc.responseCode == 200
} catch (e: Exception) {

}
return false
}
```

this method return active internet connection not only just connected!

in java

```
Boolean hasActiveInternetConnection() {
    try {
        HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection());
        urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
        urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
        urlc.setConnectTimeout(1500);
        urlc.connect();
        return (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);
    } catch (IOException e) {

        return false;
    }
}
```